# PHP if page selector

Tags: php, wordpress

The following php code selects a page and following the if statement accordingly:

```
<?php if (is_home()){ ?>
    <div class="container clear slidecontainer">
            <?php lets_get_slideshow(); ?>
```

How can i make an `if` call for ALL pages and not just the home page in this example?

Comment: you want that to show up on all pages? take out the if(), then.

Comment: And it dosent matter if my code is in index.php and shows only there? it will show on all pages?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page  ???

Comment: thank you..that was clear and easy.. didn't knew where to look though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove your if condition

Answer (score 0):

If statements are used to denote exceptions based on certain conditions. If you want code to be executed under ALL conditions (in this case, ALL pages), then you can simply omit the if statement, since there is no exception to the rule.